# Changing between 3 pictures in the UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, background, uiimageview

Hey, I was wondering how I could make the user being able to change the background of the app? I have 3 Images that the user will be able to choose from. I've seen it in many apps. How would I do this? If possible please provide some code! :)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite easy.  All you need is to set the background property of your view to an image.  Here's how it's done:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"]];
```

Now, when the user selects a different image, simply repeat the above code with a different image each time.

Comment: You can also use stuff like `NSArray` and put all your images in at launch time so that you can change images even quicker. Really depends what you're doing. Though by the sound of things, it's nothing heavy.

Comment: @Aurum: For his purposes I think that stuffing some rather large images into an array and loading this into memory might not be the best idea.  The speed increase would be rather negligible IMO. :)

Comment: When you create the array, it only contains pointers to the object. But I see what you're saying. I don't think he said that the images were large though. I suppose we can assume they are if he wants to use them as a background though...

Answer (score 0):

The question should be more clear.

You can change the background of the UIView or parent UIWindow by using,

```
  view/window.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: image]
```

or Use the UIImageView,

```
  imageView.image = image
```

Comment: Oops, you beat me.  Didn't know we were posting at the same time. :)